# mouse lag while moving numeric range slider component (SVG + Svelte)

Tags: javascript, svg, slider, range, svelte

I"m trying to code a SVG-based vertical numeric range slider component for Svelte.

My question is about transforms especially with SVG getScreenCTM () matrixes.

The component is designed to be simple and customizable via props, as shown here:

```
<!-- user markup file .svelte -->
<SVGVerticalSlider 
  title="100 units range"
  value={50}
  units=""
  min={0}
  max={100}
  step={1}
  major={10}
  minor={2.5}
/>
```

It works by displaying a range from {min} to {max} with a graduated track with {minor} and {major} lines and labels every major line, with a progrssion of {step}, and displays a labelled draggable arrow with {value + "  + units} on it.

The coordinate system used in SVG is from {YMIN} to {YMAX} by {YSTEP} so I use a linear interpolation function to compute the values:

```
// linear interpolation function
const lerp = (Xa, Ya, Xb, Yb, x) => Ya + (x - Xa) * (Yb - Ya) / (Xb - Xa)
```

The arrow function is drawn in a  group inside the SVG:

```
<g 
  class="slider" 
  transform={ 'translate(0,' + Y_VALUE + ')' } 
  on:mousedown={DND.start}
  on:mousemove={DND.move}
  on:mouseup={DND.end}
  on:mouseleave={DND.end}>
    <!-- path_point  = simple fat arrow draw pointing on Y_VALUE at (0, 0) -->
    <path d={path_points} style={ 'fill:' + bg + ';' }/>
    <text x="10" y="3" class="fat-arrow">{ formatted_value } </text>
</g>
```

In the DND.move() event listner I copmpute successif clicks positions, performing a matrix  CTM operation, and then compute the diff of two positions, so I can compute Y_COUNT = offset.y / YSTEP the number of steps while drag and droppoing mouse onto the inlined  SVG.

So the reactive bindings are:

```
let formatted_value = 0  

$: formatted_value = units ? value.toFixed(2) + ' ' + units : value

$: if (init) {
  Y_VALUE = lerp (min, YMIN, max, YMAX, value)   
  init = false
} else {

  // value += Y_COUNT * step  ...   

  if (Y_COUNT > 0)
    value += Math.floor (Y_COUNT) * step
  else
    value += Math.ceil(Y_COUNT) * step

  // new value of the cursor in SVG coordinates:
  Y_VALUE = lerp (min, YMIN, max, YMAX, value)

   // range guards (max) 
  if (value >= max) {
    value = max
    Y_VALUE = YMAX    
  }

  // range guards (min)
  if (value <= min) {
    value = min
    Y_VALUE = YMIN
  } 
}
```

WHAT'S DONE HERE ?

- mouse position is recorded each time move() event id triggered
- diffing two consecutive positions gives me offset.y
- compute Y_COUNT = offset.y / YSTEP gives us the steps amount to move the arrow
- compute the new user value of the component, counting in integer part of Y_COUNT (Math.floor or Math.ceil)
- compute the new Y_VALUE of the arrow position and bind iit on the SVG markup

PROBLEM:

I can observe a lag between mouse pointer position and effective computed position of the arrow, so mouse pointer and arrow position don't stick together !

I'have tried with various numeric scales

```
scale         min      max      step
----------------------------------------
normalized    1        100      1
big_money     0        350000   2500
percentage    0        5        0.1
```

.. and lagging effect doesn't rely clearly on scale spread and

How to fix that ?

HTML + JS + Svelte code of the component (200+ lines of code)

```
<!-- this is an attempt to build a nice SVG vertical numeric range slider for Svelte -->

<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte'

  export let title = 'default-title'

  export let min = 0
  export let max = 100
  export let step = 1
  export let major = 10
  export let minor = 5
  export let value = 50
  export let units = '' // whatever: €, %, ...

  // markers list
  let markers = []
  let majors = []
  let minors = []

  /**

  COordinate Systèm

  user (component) level      min      max      step     value    offset      count

    (tranform lerp)

  internal 0..100 range       YMIN     YMAX     YSTEP    Y_VALUE   Y_OFFSET  Y_COUNT    
  SVG coordinates                                                    

     (transfo-rm ScreenCTM)

  client cords (mouse)                          client.step event clientY offset.y                    

*/  

  // linear interpolation function
  const lerp = (Xa, Ya, Xb, Yb, x) => Ya + (x - Xa) * (Yb - Ya) / (Xb - Xa) 

  const XMIN = 0
  const YMIN = 0
  const XMAX = 50
  const YMAX = 100

  // initialisation phase flag
  let init = true

  // internal variable representing Y
  let Y_VALUE = 0

  // internam step
  let YSTEP0 = lerp (min, YMIN, max, YMAX, step)
  let YSTEP = 1.0 * (YMAX - YMIN) / ((max - min) /  step)

//  console.log (YSTEP)
//  console.log (YSTEP0)


  // internal step count
  let Y_COUNT = 0

  // user scale steps count
  let y_count = 0

  // Y_OFFSET inside SVG coords
  let Y_OFFSET = 0

  let bg = 'yellow'

  let yaxis = {
    x1: 0, y1: 0,
    x2: 0, y2: 95
  }


  let formatted_value = 0 

  $: formatted_value = units ? value.toFixed(2) + ' ' + units : value

  $: if (init) {
    Y_VALUE = lerp (min, YMIN, max, YMAX, value)   
    init = false
  } else {
     let yamount = 0    

     // without Math.floor or Math.ceil, it simply would be:
     // value += Y_COUNT * step   

     // but in fact we're doing step-by-step:
     if (Y_COUNT > 0) {
       // if (Y_COUNT < 1) Y_COUNT = 1

       yamount = Math.ceil (Y_COUNT) * step
     } else {

       // if (Y_COUNT > -1) Y_COUNT = -1
       yamount = Math.floor (Y_COUNT) * step
     }

     value +=  yamount

     Y_VALUE = lerp (min, YMIN, max, YMAX, value)

    if (value >= max) {
      value = max
      Y_VALUE = YMAX    
    }


    if (value <= min) {
      value = min
      Y_VALUE = YMIN
    } 

  }

  //  example path: 
  let path_points = 'M0,0 L10,-8 L50,-8 L50,8 L10,8 Z'

  // Drag'n DRop is kept inside a closure (IIFE)
  // so internal vriables are kept outside  (theoretically) of Svelte's binding mechansim
  const DND = (() => {
    let svg = null
    let CTM = null
    let ICTM = null
    let stepSVGPoint = null

    let selected = null
    let offset = { x:0,   y: 0}
    let position = { x:0, y: 0}

    // adapted from http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/tutorials/svg/interactive/dragging/
    const getMousePosition = (event) => {
      if (event.touches) { event = event.touches[0]; }

      let transformed = {
        x: (event.clientX - CTM.e) / CTM.a,
        y: (event.clientY - CTM.f) / CTM.d 
      }

      return transformed
    }

    const findSVGRoot = (element) => {
      const root = element.parentElement.parentElement

      return root
    } 

    const start = (event) => {
      if (selected === null) {
        selected = event.target
        svg = findSVGRoot (selected)
        CTM = svg.getScreenCTM( )
        ICTM = CTM.inverse()

        event.preventDefault ()

        position = getMousePosition (event)
        offset = { x:0, y: 0 }

        bg = 'green'


      }
    }

    const move = (event) => {
      // console.log (svg)

      if (selected) {
        event.preventDefault ()

        const npos = getMousePosition (event)

        offset.x = (npos.x - position.x)
        offset.y = (npos.y - position.y)

        Y_COUNT = (offset.y / YSTEP) 

        // hold ancient position
        position = npos

        bg = 'red' 

        console.clear ()
        console.log ('offset.y', offset.y)
        console.log ('Y_COUNT', Y_COUNT)
        //     console.log ('offset.y', offset.y)
      }
    }

    const end = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault ()

      selected = null
      offset = null
      position = null

      bg = 'yellow'
    }

    const click = (event) => {    }

    return { init, start, move, end, click }

  }) ()



  onMount (() => {
    let major_step = min
    let minor_step = min

    while (minor_step <= max) {
      const ym = lerp (min, YMIN, max, YMAX, minor_step)

      minors [ minors.length] = {
        x1: 0,   y1: ym,
        x1: 2.5, y2: ym, 
      }

      minor_step += minor
    }

    while (major_step <= max) {
      const ym = lerp (min, YMIN, max, YMAX, major_step) 

      majors [ majors.length] = {
        x1: -5,   y1: ym,
        x1: 7.5,  y2: ym, 
      }

      markers [ markers.length] = {
        x: 10,
        y: ym,
        label: major_step
      }

      major_step += major
    }

  })


</script>

<h1> #{ title }</h1>

<svg 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
  viewBox="-5 -15 55 125" 
  width="120" height="280"
  on:click={DND.click}>

  <g class="ruler">
    <line 
      x1="{ yaxis.x1 }" y1="{ yaxis.y1 }" 
      x2="{ yaxis.x2 }" y2="{ yaxis.y2 }" 
    />

    {#each majors as maj }
      <line x1={maj.x1} y1={maj.y1} x2={maj.x2} y2={maj.y2} />
    {/each}

    {#each markers as mm_text }
      <text x="{ mm_text.x }" y="{ mm_text.y }"> { mm_text.label} </text>
    {/each}

    {#each minors as min }
      <line x1={min.x1} y1={min.y1} x2={min.x2} y2={min.y2} />
    {/each}
  </g>

  <g 
    class="slider" 
    transform={ 'translate(0,' + (Y_VALUE) + ')'} 
    on:mousedown={DND.start}
    on:mousemove={DND.move}
    on:mouseup={DND.end}
    on:mouseleave={DND.end}>

      <path d={path_points} style={ 'fill:' + bg + ';' }/>
      <text x="10" y="3" class="fat-arrow">{ formatted_value } </text>

  </g>
</svg>

<p> Y_COUNT (internal): { Y_COUNT.toFixed(3)} </p>
<p> YSTEP (internal): { YSTEP.toFixed(3)} </p>
<p>Y_VALUE (internal): { Y_VALUE.toFixed(3)} </p>
<p>value: { value.toFixed(3)} </p>

<style>
  svg {
    background-color: lightgrey;
  }

  line {
    stroke-width: 0.5;
    stroke: rgb(0, 0, 255);
  }

  text {
    font-size: 0.35em;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
  }

  text.fat-arrow {
    font-size: 0.55em;
    color: rgb(192, 48, 16);
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  path {
    fill: rgb(255, 255, 64 );
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 0.5;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

</style>
```

Comment: Please include an [mcve] so we can see the problem in action.

Comment: @Paul : juste import the full code above in your app and invoke it using the parameters on top exports (example in the post), I think it's no so difficult.

Is there a kind of fiddle / REPL where Svelte 3 runs ? I could paste the code in it ...

Comment: The best way to get answers, is to not make people have to do extra work to get your example running.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found by myself : I have mistaken with maths...

Saying, I has the bounds and steps for the user input, AND the same converted in SVG coordinates:

```
 user input      SVG
 ------------------------
 min: 0          YMIN: 0
 max: 10000      YMAX: 100
 step: 100       YSTEP: ?
```

The right way for computing YSTEP was not:

```
// NO !!!
YSTEP = lerp (min, YMIN, max, YMAX, step)
```

... since I decided earlier to flip up-side-down the slider scale, but rather:

```
// YES !!!
YSTEP = step * (YMAX - YMIN) / (max - min)
```

which allows me to have positive (either negative) steps !!!

so I can close the issue. All works fine for me, reagards ;-)